# Postgresql combine multiple query taking operation

Tags: postgresql

My data consists of two columns and 1024 rows. I have created the formula like this:

```
SELECT wavelength, (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) / (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END) AS reflectance   FROM ( SELECT wavelength, reflectance FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * FROM table_name) As foo WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)) bar
```

Now the calculated formula output will be like this:

```
wavelength  reflectance
341.6       -48.4615384615384615
347.9       -80.0000000000000000
349.5       -630.0000000000000000
355.8       -160.0000000000000000
357.4       -68.8888888888888889
363.6        1.60000000000000000000
365.2       -315.0000000000000000
371.5       -75.0000000000000000
```

Now taking this as input and I want to apply formula

- reflectance corresponding value as r
- reflectance maximum value as rmax
- reflectance minimum value as rmin

Formula

reflectance=((r-rmin)/(rmax-rmin))*100

Output: I want to display wavelength and output column.

How to combine this formula query into the above query and execute this task in a single  query operation?

Query tried

```
SELECT 
 wavelength,
   (reflectance - MIN(reflectance))/(MAX(reflectance)-MIN(reflectance))*100 As reflectance FROM (
SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM (
   SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
   FROM
     (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
      FROM deodar) As foo 
   WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
) results )bar
```

It shows ERROR: column "bar.wavelength" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say rmin and rmax in your formula, what wavelengths are these values supposed to span over? All of the 1024 reflectances in the table, or +/- a specific range of wavelength, or are there duplicate rows of the same wavelength (i.e. 5 rows for 355.8 with different reflectance values each) and they are supposed to span over those?

Comment: Then where does the rmin and rmax come from? For example, let's say I am trying to calculate it for wavelength 355.8 using (only) the example table in your post. Is rmin going to be "-48.4615384615384615", or "-630.0", or what?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a little bit better now... I updated my answer with another query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your **outermost** query, you are aggregating reflectance but not wavelength. So even though you have sets of rows for each wavelength, you are not telling PostgreSQL to **combine** the rows where the wavelength is the same when calculating the reflectance.

Try adding a `GROUP BY` clause to your outer query which would group the bar.wavelength values.

Change your main (last) query to look like this (the new `GROUP BY` clause is the last line):

```
SELECT 
 wavelength,
   (reflectance - MIN(reflectance))/(MAX(reflectance)-MIN(reflectance))*100 As reflectance
FROM (
SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM (
   SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
   FROM
     (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
      FROM deodar) As foo 
   WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
) results )bar
GROUP BY bar.wavelength`
```

### UPDATE

Ok, I think I now understand what you are trying to do a bit better... Try this version:

```
SELECT
  wavelength,
  (reflectance - rmin) / (rmax - rmin) * 100 AS reflectance
FROM (SELECT
  wavelength,
  (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
  (CASE
    WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance)
  END)
  AS reflectance,
  MIN(reflectance) as rmin,
  MAX(reflectance) as rmax
FROM (SELECT
  wavelength,
  reflectance
FROM (SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS RowNumber,
  *
FROM deodar) AS foo
WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)) results) bar
```

Comment: It shows ERROR: column "results.wavelength" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.